# Updating recordset returns 500 error

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I can read from Database, and my other projects (Using ASPMaker read/write records), but thought I'd get my hands dirty instead of cheating, but when trying to update a record I get a 500 error. The directory has read write permissions. Could someone check through my code to see first I've made a mistake.

```
<!--#include file="Connection.asp"-->

<%
Dim DeleteRS, Query
Set DeleteRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Query = "Select * From notices Where [notice].[approved] = False AND [notice].[Notice_ID] = " & Request.qureystring("n")
response.write(Query)

DeleteRS.Open Query, adoCon, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
DeleteRS.Delete

DeleteRS.Close
Set DeleteRS = Nothing
Set Query = Nothing

%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should enable showing detailed error messages on the webserver so that you get more information than just a 500 error.

Your code has multiple problems:

- You trust user input: you build your sql code dynamically and use whatever value is provided `Request.querystring("n")`. See [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and use parameters
- Spelling errors:

  - Request.**qureystring**
  - Select * From **notices** Where [**notice**].[a... 
    (Unless you do a join you don't have to repeat the tablename in every
    column)
- Never change data based on a HTTP GET request. If you want to delete (or update) a row create an HTML form and POST the id that needs to be deleted.
- You don't need to use a recordset object to delete a row. Now you are talking to the database twice: once to retrieve the row, once to delete it. Just create a delete statement:

  ```
  Dim command

  command = Server.CreateObject("adodb.command")
  command.ActiveConnection = adoCon
  command.Execute "DELETE FROM notices WHERE approved = False AND id = ?", array(Request.querystring("n"))
  command.Close

  Set command = Nothing
  ```

The question mark is a parameter and the value is provided in the array.